# Spliting the values of column into new column within a dataframe to filter

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe, which looks as follows,

```
Head1 Header2
ABC SAP (+115590), GRN (+426250)    
EFG HES3 (-6350), CMT (-1902)   
HIJ CORT (-19440), API (+177)   
KLM AAD (-25488), DH(-1341) ,DSQ(+120001)
SOS MFA (-11174), 13A2 (+19763)
```

And I need to split the second column with a comma and create new column within the same data frame. In addition to that, I need to take out all values within the brackets and create another column with that numeric information to filter further.

So far I am able to do it with a not so elegant piece of code and it's so lengthy as follows,

```
Trans = 'file.txt'
Trans = pd.read_csv(Trans, sep="\t", header=0)
Trans.columns=["RNA","PCs"]


  # Here I changed the dtype to string to do split
    Trans.PCs=Trans.PCs.astype(str)
 #I took out those first part of second column into new column PC1
    Trans["PC1"]=Trans.PCs.str.extract('(\w*)', expand=True)
    #Here I splited the neuwmric informationf rom first part
    Trans[['Strand1','Dis1']] =  Trans.PCs.str.extract('([+-])(\d*)', expand=True)
 Trans.head()


   Head  Header2                     Head1  Strand1  Dis1
    ABC  SAP (+11559), GRN (+42625)  SAP        +     115590
    EFG  HES3 (-6350), CMT (-1902)   HES3       -     6350
    HIJ  CORT (-19440), API (+177)   CORT       -     19440
    KLM  AAD (-25488), DH(-1341)     AAD        -     25488
    SOS  MFA (-11174), 13A2 (+19763) MFA        -     11174
```

And I need the above data frame to split again, so I using the following piece of code for second part of column 2

> ```
>         # this for second part of 2nd column
>         Trans["PC2"]=Trans.PCs.str.split(',').str.get(1)
>         # did for neumric information
>         Trans[['Strand2','Dis2']] =  Trans.PC2.str.extract('([+-])(\d*)', expand=True)
> ```

```
Trans['PC2']=Trans.PC2.str.replace(r"\(.*\)","")

 # At this point the daframe looks like this,
Head    Header2                Head1         Strand1          Dis1        Head2     Strand2 Dis2
ABC  SAP (+11559), GRN (+42625) SAP     +   115590      GRN  +   426250
EFG HES3 (-6350), CMT (-1902)   HES3    -   6350    CMT  -   1902
HIJ CORT (-19440), API (+177)   CORT    -   19440   API  +   177
KLM AAD (-25488), DH(-1341)     AAD     -   25488   DH   - 1341
SOS MFA (-11174), 13A2 (+19763),DSQ(+120001)    MFA     -   11174   13A2  +  19763
```

> ```
>     Trans=Trans.fillna(0)
>     Trans.Dis1=Trans.Dis1.astype(int)
>     Trans.Dis2=Trans.Dis2.astype(int)
> ```

```
# Here I am filtering the rows based on Dis1 and Dis2 columns from daframe
>         Trans_Pc1=Trans.loc[:,"lncRNA":"Dis1"].query('Dis1 >= 100000')
>         Trans_Pc2=Trans.loc[:,"PC2":"Dis2"].query('Dis2 >= 100000')
>         TransPC1=Trans_Pc1.PC1
>         TransPC2=Trans_Pc2.PC2
>         TransPCs=pd.concat([TransPC1,TransPC2])
```

this looks like this,

```
Header
SAP
GRN
DSQ
```

Even though the script is lengthy is working , But I have problem when the second column has rows with more than 2 commas separated value like here in the row,

```
KLM AAD (-25488), DH(-1341) ,DSQ(+120001)
```

It has three comma separated values, I know I have to repeat the split again but my data frame is really big and has many rows with unequal comma separated values.Like for example, some rows has 2 comma separated values for column 2 and some has 5 and so on.

Any better way to filter my frame would be great.
In the end, I am aiming a  dataframe as follows,

```
header
SAP
GRN
DSQ
```

Any help or suggestions would be really great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['ABC', 'SAP (+115590), GRN (+426250)'],
        ['EFG', 'HES3 (-6350), CMT (-1902)'],
        ['HIJ', 'CORT (-19440), API (+177)'],  
        ['KLM', 'AAD (-25488), DH(-1341) ,DSQ(+120001)'],
        ['SOS', 'MFA (-11174), 13A2 (+19763)'],
    ], columns=['Head1', 'Header2'])

df1 = df.Header2.str.split(',', expand=True)

regex = r'(?P<Head>\w+).*\((?P<Strand>[+-])(?P<Dis>.*)\)'
extract = lambda df: df.iloc[0].str.extract(regex, expand=True)

extracted = df1.groupby(level=0).apply(extract)

df2 = extracted.stack().unstack([2, 1])

colseries = df2.columns.to_series()
df2.columns = colseries.str.get(0).astype(str) + colseries.str.get(1).astype(str)

pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the simple way, but as you can see in post I need to filter further based on the Dis* columns and return those rows which have Dis* >=100000, so when there are numerous Dis* columns how to get it in one line I mean, the following is what I tried when there is only two Dis columns,  Trans_Pc1=Trans.loc[:,"Head1":"Dis1"].query('Dis1 >= 100000')
>         Trans_Pc2=Trans.loc[:,"Head2":"Dis2"].query('Dis2 >= 100000')